# Update MySQL database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form with a submit button and a close button. If a user enters something and hits the submit button, an answer will be posted and saved inside the database. If a user clicks the close button, inside the database an entry will be updated with the current timestamp.

Everything is working fine but now I would like to make those changes if someone clicks the close button with AJAX so that I do not have to reload the page.

The code for my submit button is:

```
<input type='submit' id='setclosed' value='Close Ticket' name='setclosed' class='btn btn-warning' />
```

Now if someone clicks the submit button, the followin code will be activated inside my current file (so no external file for php processing):

```
if (isset ($_POST['setclosed'])) {    // Setze Status auf Closed
    $updatecontent_success=array('stamp_closed'=>$localtime);
    updateContractTicket($show_details,$updatecontent_success);
}
```

What do I have to do so that the database entry will be updated, but the page does not reload?

Comment: Could you please post the code that makes the ajax request?

Comment: I dont have any ajax code yet. I just do that action with PHP and now I am looking for a solution that I do not have to reload the page when someone clicks on close

Comment: Well you will have to use ajax. Read up on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I know that I have to use AJAX and I already read a few things about it but I need one example with my code to see how it works so I am asking if someone can show me what code I need to make my button working with AJAX

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick AJAX example to get you going. You should separate you PHP and Javascript/HTML code. I'll write out the two files.

In your HTML file you'll have the html code and the javascript that will make the request, and then alert the user that the request went through. Make sure that your form doesn't submit anything.

-HTML

```
<button type='button' id='setclosed' name='setclosed'   class='btn btn-warning'>Close Ticket</button>
```

-Javascript

```
$('#setclosed').click(function() {
  $.post('ajax.php',
    {   cmd: 'setclosed' },
    function(data) {
        alert('AJAX request was made');
    }, 'json'
  );
});
```

The ajax sends a POST variable read by the PHP as `$_POST["cmd"]`. This will let your php execute the necessary code for that command, echo back a status, and then exit the php file.

-PHP

```
if ($_POST["cmd"]=='setclosed') {
  $updatecontent_success=array('stamp_closed'=>$localtime);
  $updateContractTicket($show_details,$updatecontent_success);
  echo json_encode(array('Status' => 'Ok'));
  exit(0);
}
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not working and I am really do not know why. Can you tell me what the ajax.php should be? I do not have a ajax.php file?!

Comment: Just create a php file, and name it ajax.php. The file will just be pure php.

Comment: What should be inside the ajax.php file? The if ($_POST... command?

Comment: Yes. All of that php. I won't do it for you though. Best of luck figuring it out

Comment: Hmm..I did that but as soon as I click on the button, nothing happens. :(